# C++ - assignment of parameters to local variables in function header

Tags: c++

I have recently come across a constructor that looked like this:

`classname::classname(index_t m, index_t n) : m(m), n(n) {...}`

However, I am not sure what `: m(m), n(n)` does. I think it assigns the parameters `index_t m, index_t n` to local variables of the same type and name - would this observation be correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called *initialization list* and it's used to initialize the non-static members. You usually use them if you want to avoid double initialization of the members (if you assign the member in the body constructor, the memebers alredy exist, so you are "doubling" the init process).

You can find more info on the reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor